# How to call out a variable that is passed from within 4 classes

Tags: java, loops, class

I have 4 classes, `Main`, `class A`, `class B`, `class C`.
I initiated a variable in Main, outside a loop_1 : `int x=0`
and then passed it into `class A` that uses a loop_2, and then from there straight into `class B` which is a part of that loop and right into `class C`.

I intended that after `class A` would finish the loop I'll get System.out.Println with X.

The problem is that I get x=0 every time. I have a **checkUp** System.out.println in `class C` and I see it grow there, But as I try to print x from class `class A` I always get x=0.

Note:
I have

**Main Class**

```
public class SocketMain
   {

public void mainMethod{
 int x=0;
 for (int edition = 0 ; edition<29 ; edition++){
  classA.Method1(x);

 x=0;
  }
}
```

**class A (SelfNote : // InstrumentPage)**

```
 public class classA 
{

public static void Method1(int x)

{
for (int loopCounter = 0 ; loopCounter <29 ; loopCounter ++){
  classB.Method2(x);


 }


if (x=0)
System.outprintln("FirstIf" +x);

if (x>0)
System.out.println ("SecondIf" +x);
    }
```

**Class B (SelfNote : //TestClockOfInstrument)**

```
 public class classb
          {
public static void Method2(int x)
{

    classC.Method3(x);



}
```

**Class C (SelfNote : //SocketChanges)**

```
 public class classc
{
public static void Method3 (int x)
{
 if (someThingHappens == 1)
  x++;
 System.out.println ("Check X" +x);
```

}

Comment: @BackSlash I don't believe this is an exact duplicate of that one.  A person asking this question is unlikely to understand the significance of the concepts explained in that other question.  So marking this question as a duplicate is more likely to confuse the OP than to help them.  That's my opinion anyway.

Comment: Maybe you should return the updated value, instead of trying to change the value passed in.

Comment: @BackSlash Its a project I'm working on, that has 4 classes. I deleted all the rest and edited it for nearly 45 minutes so it would be easy to understand. I don't understand why did you mark it as a duplicate. I just need so advise

Comment: @dimaedunov because you are passing a value in and expecting it to change. If you read and understand the answer, you'll see why your current solution doesn't work. Your method essentially receives a new int that has the same value. So changing it, only changes it locally and not the original.

Comment: @matt , Can you be more specific. How do I return it straight into classA?

Comment: I have fixed some class / Methods in the code. It was wrong. Sorry

Comment: replace void with int. `int method3(int x){ if(condition) return x+1; else return x;}` then `int method2(int x){ return C.method3(x);}`